# Copy info from build-in db to server db (login/password are provided)

Tags: asp.net, sql, .net, database, ssms

I need to copy tables and other information from build-in database (when in visual studio you press File->New Website -> ASP.NET Website , you will have template project with build in db with membership tables and stored procedures) to my server db.

Because I need to use membership with my custom database.

In config file I added (server, login and password are valid, so you can test):

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="EntitiesCustom" connectionString="server=176.9.119.68,3333\sqlexpress;Database=21895_database;User ID=34895_user;Password=gIOjOPOP8yui" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>

<membership>
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="EntitiesCustom" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </membership>
```

But if I want to use my custom db with membership I need to copy all the tables from build-in db, because otherwise I have error:

```
Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.
Stack Trace: 
[SqlException (0x80131904): Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +109
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +126
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +239
```

I tried to use sql management studio but I could only add my custom db, I even don't know how to add `ASPNETDB.MDF` file disk (file of build-in db). And even if I managed to add that file, I don't know how to copy all the information from build-in db to my custom server db (I found restore function in sql management studio but it seems to work only with databases on the server (if I try to restore server db)).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here

I need to use

```
aspnet_regsql.exe -S DBServerName -U DBLogin -P DBPassword -A all -d DBName
```

From microsoft site this exe file is situated [drive:]\%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\version

It automatically created all proper folders. So that togather with my config file (I had to change membership connection string, I provided it in my question) it work perfectly.